# Is there a way for Rabbit MQ consumer to get the latest message on init?

Tags: rabbitmq

I am looking to replace an in-house key-value store and dispatch system and I keep hearing that RabbitMQ may be a solution.

I understand that sends and receives messages using queues, and that these events are triggered by producers creating messages, and consumers receiving them.

But what happens if a consumer is created after a message was sent? Can the consumer ask the queue what its last message was? If not, do I need to include some sort of database to store these messages? Or am I looking for some other technology?

A use case is that I want a GUI to get/set parameters that are used by other apps on a local network. On initialization, the GUI needs to know what the last values were.

In an attempt to answer my own question, it may be that RabbitMQ is not what I am looking for. I may want to instead use Kafka which stores its latest key:value pair in a table. Or I may want to use Redis. What do you think?

Thank you for your assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found a satisfactory answer to my question. I'm looking to create a request-reply model, which RabbitMQ is quite capable of handling. Upon opening the GUI, it sends a request to some other process for some variable, stored either in memory or in a database. That process responds with the requested data. Easy enough.

Answer (score -3):

i suggest to integrate rabbitmq with redis, i make an implementation for this approach as poc. it's ok for me for handling this case.

Redis seems like a straightforward choice. It provides the capability to store the latest state of each parameter and allows for quick retrieval. However, if your system also requires decoupled, asynchronous message passing for other purposes, you might still consider using RabbitMQ in conjunction with Redis, where RabbitMQ handles message passing, and Redis maintains the state.

for more details about rabbitMQ, please check this docs
https://www.rabbitmq.com/documentation.html

for more details about redis, please check
https://redis.io/docs/

this a sudo code for rabbitmq with redis

General Architecture

- Applications (Producers): These are your applications that produce messages, such as updates to parameters.
- RabbitMQ (Message Broker): It receives messages from producers and routes them to the appropriate queues.
- Worker Services (Consumers): These services consume messages from RabbitMQ queues and update Redis with the latest key-value pairs.
- Redis (Data Store): Stores the latest state of each key-value pair.
- GUI Application: Queries Redis directly to get the latest state of parameters on initialization.

Comment: AI generated answers are explicitly banned

Comment: @possum, i make a poc of this appraoch to handle this case, i think it's ok.

Comment: Any AI generated answer is *explicitly* banned, regardless of content.   The policy is linked on the side of every page, but you can find it here https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-generative-ai-e-g-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1